# How can I process the data received from NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsnotifications

I have create a class MyConnection that extends NSURLConnection. I have implemented some delegate methods. I am able to print the data received from the URL call. However when I pass the MyConnection instance into MyHelper class, I do not get the data received in the MyConnection class. I tried putting a sleep call between the two task and still no luck. connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method is called only after the current code block is finished. Is there a way to handle this issue without getting into notification?

```
MyConnection *con = [[MyConnection alloc] init];    
[con fetchDataFromServer];
//sleep call here
MyHelper *myHelper = [[MyHelper alloc ] initWithConnection:con];
[myHelper processDataFoundInConnection];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `NSURLConnection` (by default) processes asynchronously **on the current runloop** (so it's not asynchronous in that it doesn't use a secondary thread).  So you can either spin the runloop manually or use the `sendSynchronousRequest:...` method.